# Is it true that $\widehat{f(x,0)}(\xi) = \widehat{f}(\xi,0)$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory, schwartz-space

Let $f \in S(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and $g(x)= f(x,0)$. What is the relationship between $\widehat{g}$ and $\widehat{f}$?

It's clear that $g \in S(\mathbb{R})$ so both $f$ and $g$ have a Fourier transform.
I expect something like $\widehat g(\xi)= \widehat f(\xi,0)$ but starting from the integral definitions gets me nowhere... Any ideas on how to proceed? Thanks!

Comment: Think of $f(x,t)=\sin(xt)$.

Comment: Yeah... so my expectation is false. Is there a clear relation none the less?

Comment: Personally I can't see why one would exist. Thinking of the two variables as space and time, why would the spatial frequencies at time $t=0$ have anything to do with the space-time frequencies for a fixed time frequency $\omega=0$? Maybe there is a relation, I don't know, but it's not obvious to me why we should expect one to exist. The function $\hat{f}(\xi,0)$ is using global information about the signal $f$ in time but $\widehat{f(x,0)}(\xi)$ only "sees" one time point $t=0$.

Comment: I guess you are right. I assume the point of the exercise was to see what doesn't work, which I thank you for helping me with!

Comment: If you find out there is an interesting relation I'd enjoy learning more.